# Replacing the value of env:define with an environment variable in AKS

Tags: aks, sitecore-managed-cloud

Has anyone successfully replaced the value of `env:define` app setting?

I have tried using `SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_env:define` however it seems that AKS does not support using the colon in an environment variable name.

I've contacted Sitecore who advised trying `SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_env__define` however that also didn't work.

Comment: Does the setting already exist in the web config? The override only happens when the key is present in the web config on startup. Typically I use a blank value.

Comment: Hey, yes it already exists.  Its defined as <add key="env:define" value="Local" />

Comment: Interesting! could you please give a with this - `SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_envdefine` or `SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_env_define` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes doesn't support the colon character (`:`) in environment variables names, as reported in this Github issue on the Kubernetes repository [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53201).

The workaround suggested by Sitecore using double underscores (`__`) to replace a colon in the environment variable name works for an ASP.NET Core application, but not for an ASP.NET framework application.

You should be able to replace the value of your `env:define` app setting with an environment variable, defining instead its default value in the web.config with the following syntax that explicitly defines the name of the environment variable associated to:

```
<add key="env:define" value="$(env:SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_ENV_DEFINE)" />
```

With the syntax above, the name of the environment variable to add in your Kubernetes specs would be `SITECORE_APPSETTINGS_ENV_DEFINE`.

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: This looks to have worked.  Just getting a colleague to test it as well